# Front end engineering : Best way to implement a step by step check out cart

Tags: angularjs, jquery, front-end, e-commerce

I have implemented a checkout cart like this :[image]

Navigation rules are as follows :

- User can move to next step only on completing the current step.
- But he is free to click on the previous tab and edit the past information.

Currently I have implemented this in a single page using jquery. However, the code appears extremely messy with lots of show and hides.
Is it a better solution to implement each tab as a separate page with separate url and use session variables to store data from previous tab ?
Or should I go for a rewrite with angular ?

Comment: Isn’t it bad U/X to have so many disparate steps to perform a checkout?

Comment: That was my feeling as well. But I don't have a say in the U/X :(

Comment: Off topic, but if that is your feeling, I suggest you include instrumentation/metrics of step completion. You can use this data later to argue for a simpler workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Jquery when using Angularjs you're doing it wrong, except if you do it from a directive.

Make a better usage of the templating capabilities of angularjs, it decreases all need to manipulate the DOM :

- You can use ng-show/ng-hide to manage the display of your components.
- Form handling, binding, validation is managed by Angularjs, you may need some custom directives check the documentation and the tons of samples online.
- Let's say all your form are named "formX" where X is the number. You can put on each block wrapping each form except the first : `ng-disabled="formX.$invalid`". This will prevent from opening the others part of the forms as long the previous one are not completed.

> Is it a better solution to implement each tab as a separate page with separate url and use session variables to store data from previous tab ?

Personnaly I have that, but I use ui-router (replace default router component of angularjs), so implemented as stated in a SPA so I don't need to store states in the session variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not currently using angular. What I implied was, is it worth rewriting the jquery code in angular , especially for better maintainability - somebody else may have to handle the code when I leave. I have rephrased the last line of the qn concerning angular, sorry for being vague.

Comment: From your answer it certainly looks like it is worth a rewrite in angular.

Comment: If it is for a professional job, ask them time for rewriting in another technologies may not pass. Otherwise if you can, make sure to learn the basics of angularJS : services, routings, forms, providers. Directives are for more advanced usage you shouldn't need that much to implements your own.

Comment: Make sure you look into other single-page frameworks as well, just to see if any of them suit you better than Angular. React/Flux, VueJS, etc. But certainly using any one of these is better than a bunch of jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow that you described (with multiple views and stateful steps) seems sufficiently complex that you will certainly benefit from using some sort of framework. Angular is a good choice, especially if you are already familiar with it.